# CONNECT A IR Distance Sensor (GP2Y0A710K0F) TO A WAV SHIELD

Tags: arduino, mp3, sensors, proximity

I AM TRYING TO CONNECT A GP2Y0A710K0F IR Distance Sensor TO A Adafruit Wave Shield for Arduino Kit - v1.1

I DO NOT HAVE ANY EXPERIENCE IN WIRING, PLEASE, HELP. I JUST NEED TO FIGURE OUT WHERE DO THE WIRES GO.
THE IMAGE BELOW IS THE ONLY REFERENCE THAT I HAVE AND I DON'T UNDERSTAND IT. COULD ANYONE PLEASE HELP ME, EITHER BY A PICTURE, OR SHOWING ME STEP BY STEP HOW TO WIRE IT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question does not belong here, because it doesn't involve programming.

That said, the Wave Shield is for playing mp3s, and it doesn't make sense to connect the IR sensor to it.

The IR sensor needs to be connected to the GND and 5V supply of the Arduino, and the Vo output connect to one of the Arduino pins. Read the voltage on the output pin with `analogRead()`. The result from 0 to 1023 is related the 1/distance.

Comment: Ok, you are absolutely right. I had to post it like this, because it wouldn't let me attach a picture, because I'm new to this forum. I got the sensor working, and the serial monitor shows a reading. Now, could you help me figure out a sketch for arduino, that would enable my wavshield to play one of the music tracks every time something is 3 ft away?

Comment: @krizz [This document](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-wave-shield-audio-shield-for-arduino.pdf) has an example sketch where a song is played if a button is pressed. You will adapt the `loop()` to read the IR sensor and play a song if the reading is higher than a certain number. Find the number by trial and error. Once you have a start on this, you can post a new question.

Comment: What example exactly?

Comment: @krizz The example code with explanations starts on page 71, and the entire code is repeated starting on p. 76. You will have to adapt it, but the explanations of how it works will be helpful. There are a bunch of links at the top of p. 86 that are similar.

Comment: I adapted it, I am using the "Smoothing" sketch from Arduino, with the wavehc_ play 6 complete once. When I used the sketches separately, they work, when I try to merge them, they don't.

Comment: Should I post another question about it? What category is it best?